# Maximum pool connection size

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I am using six schemas for single java application and I able to access the application only for 10mins. After some time, it keeps on loading. Finally i have received the below error in logs.

```
     java.lang.IllegalStateException: Pool closed
```

In servlet configuration, i have given the maximum pool connection size is 300.
Given the below line.

```
     <prop key="connection.pool_size">300</prop>
```

Is this enough else wil increase more? I am using both mysql and sql database.

What is maximum pool connection size for Mysql and SQl? How to resolve this problem? Thanks

Comment: I don't think your error has anything to do with your pool size.

Comment: Are you sure you close the connections each end every case? It must be done in a try-finally block.

Comment: maybe your database kills every connection after 10 mins

Comment: You have to show us your code how you use the connections

Comment: Yes. I am sure all connection are closed. i am mostly using getCurrentSession for all services.

Comment: The pool is closed, not the connection.  It almost seems like the pool thinks the application is shutting down or something.

Comment: Initially I was facing the same issue while adding new schema configuration. Hence I increased the pool size from 100 to 300 . After the problem is solved. Now I do the same, adding one more schema and receiving the same error.

Comment: `adding new schema configuration` can you share this please?  Not sure why adding a new schema would need increased connections.  Also, can you share the full stack, your full pool config (redact login credentials) and what this application is running? (spring, hibernate, etc...)

Comment: A pool size of 300 is btw far too high. As a general rule use number of cpu cores x 2

Comment: What's the `wait_timeout`?